# How i can fast read data in database?

Tags: c#, database, combobox, backgroundworker

**I have 9 comboboxentry and 9 table Paradox *.db .**Tables apply to comboboxentry.And this is work 35-38 seconds?? Need more faster.Help please.I am trying work with array but this is was bad idea time increased.

```
 *_connection.Open ();
            cmdComboboxTable1=new OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT cell FROM Table1 ;",_connection);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapComboboxTable1=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdComboboxTable1);2500records
            cmdComboboxTable2=new OleDbCommand("select DISTINCT cell from table2 where cell is not null;",_connection);79000Records
            OleDbDataAdapter adapComboboxTable2=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdComboboxTable2);
            cmdComboboxTable3=new OleDbCommand("select distinct  cell from table3 WHERE EUR_STK_CD IS NOT NULL;",_connection);80000records
            OleDbDataAdapter adapComboboxTable4=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdComboboxTable4);9records
            cmdComboboxTable4=new OleDbCommand("select cell1,cell2 FROM Table4;",_connection);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapComboboxTable4=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdComboboxTable4);

            cmdComboboxTable5=new OleDbCommand("select DISTINCT cell From Table5 ORDER BY cell;",_connection);100000records
            OleDbDataAdapter adapComboboxTable5=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdComboboxTable5);

            cmdComboboxTable6=new OleDbCommand("select distinct cell From Table6 where MODL_NM IS NOT NULL;",_connection);60000records
            OleDbDataAdapter adapComboboxTable6=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdComboboxTable6);

            cmdComboboxtable7=new OleDbCommand("select distinct cell From table7 where cell IS NOT NULL;",_connection);120 records
            OleDbDataAdapter adapComboboxTable=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdComboboxTable7);12records

            cmdComboboxTable8=new OleDbCommand("select cell FROM Table8;",_connection);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapComboboxTable8=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdComboboxTable8);

            cmdComboboxTable9=new OleDbCommand("select distinct Cell1,cell2 FROM Table9;",_connection);11records
            OleDbDataAdapter adapComboboxTable9=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdComboboxTable9);


            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();

            //StartBackgroundworker();
            bgComboboxTable9.RunWorkerAsync();
            bgComboboxTable2.RunWorkerAsync();
            bgComboboxTable3.RunWorkerAsync();
            bgComboboxTable4.RunWorkerAsync();
            bgComboboxTable5.RunWorkerAsync();

            bgComboboxTable6.RunWorkerAsync();
            bgComboboxTable7.RunWorkerAsync();
            bgComboboxTable8.RunWorkerAsync();


            //This is method in all backgrounder worker
            drComboboxTable9 = cmdComboboxTable9.ExecuteReader ();
            ListStore Table1List;
            string Table1String;
            Table9List=new ListStore(typeof(string));
            comboboxentry4.Model=Table1List;
            while(drComboboxTable1.Read()){
                Table9String=(string)drComboboxTable1["LONG_NM"];
                Table9List.AppendValues(Table1String);
            }
            //method end
            stopWatch.Stop();
            TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
                ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
                ts.Milliseconds / 10);
            Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);*
```

Answer (score 1):

Roughly I can add,

- Don't use distinct if not necessary. That kills performance.
- Check Indexes, add indexes wherever applicable. Check execution plan and decide.
- More importantly, remove all unused indexes.

Comment: Doesn't removing unused indices only help upon inserts and updates?

Comment: I am do in application search. And all records have dublicate with different ID for search in another Big Table for desired record.Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put indices on the tables so that `where` clauses work efficiently and the `dinstinct` clauses, too.

Namely:

- `cell` on `table1` and `table2`
- `cell` and `EUR_STK_CD` on `table3`
- `cell` on `table5`
- `cell` and `MODL_NM` on `table6`
- `cell` on `table7`
- `cell1` and `cell2` on `table9`